# Why i always gets the [INFO] Unable to find resource in repository?

Tags: maven-2, dependencies, maven, artifacts

greetings all
I am using maven 2 in my spring project
and when I try to build the project from the terminal using the commands (mvn clean-mvn install)

it cannot download any dependency from any of the repos, and I always gets Info like :

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.4/velocity-tools-generic-1.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'velocity-tools:velocity-tools-generic:pom:1.4' in repository first (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2//velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.4/velocity-tools-generic-1.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'velocity-tools:velocity-tools-generic:pom:1.4' in repository second (http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/)
Downloading: http://repository.jboss.com/maven2//velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.4/velocity-tools-generic-1.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'velocity-tools:velocity-tools-generic:pom:1.4' in repository jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/)
Downloading: http://maven.jahia.org/maven2/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.4/velocity-tools-generic-1.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'velocity-tools:velocity-tools-generic:pom:1.4' in repository additional (http://maven.jahia.org/maven2)
Downloading: http://208.79.234.53:8081/artifactory/libs-releases-local/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/1.4/velocity-tools-generic-1.4.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'velocity-tools:velocity-tools-generic:pom:1.4' from repository host.varaza.com (http://208.79.234.53:8081/artifactory/libs-releases-local): Error transferring file: Connection timed out
```

any ideas, why such thing occurs ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the repository [link](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/velocity-tools/velocity-tools-generic/), it looks like this `dependency` does not have an associated `pom` file.  This is the reason for the warning.

Typically, dependencies in the repository also have a pom file, which describes the project, as well as specifies its dependencies.  Maven first downloads this pom file, so that it can resolve transitive dependencies, if any.

Comment: You are right, I have downloaded the dependency on my local machine and there's no POM. But the project is working fine. It's not a show stopper.

Answer (score 3):

Maven is *just* trying to get the `pom` files from your repositories and will try for as long as it can't download them.

This is happening most probably because the libraries (dependencies) you reference don't have a `pom` file in any of the remote repositories available. This is probably normal.

However if you want to get rid of the message you could deploy *minimal* `pom` files for those dependencies in your company's repository. You can choose to just install them locally but then other developers in your team would still have those messages.

Answer (score 2):

Maven can't reach the sites where dependencies are located.

Try running

```
ping repo1.maven.org
```

or opening it in your web browser. Maybe you should set the firewall to allow Maven downloading stuff from internet.

Comment: it was downloading before but now it cannot download from any repo, and when i pinged it gives me unknown host ?

Comment: What about browser? For `http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/` you should get something like:

`    Index of /maven2/

    ../
    HTTPClient/        01-Nov-2005 05:03
    abbot/             12-Feb-2010 00:20
    acegisecurity/     23-Dec-2005 12:20
    activation/        21-Dec-2005 15:37`

Comment: the link is opened fine in the browser

Comment: If you use a proxy here's a hint: http://maven.apache.org/general.html#proxy-needed

Comment: look i checked that the repo link is working fine, and the dependency is in this link, and the connection is fine and i am not using a proxy

Comment: `ping repo1.maven.org` worked fine. As suggested in the proxy-needed link, after adding proxy settings to ~/.m2/settings.xml, it started working fine. Here is my settings.xml: `<settings>
    <proxies>
        <proxy>
            <id>my-proxy</id>
            <active>true</active>
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <host>123.1.2.3</host>
            <port>1234</port>
        </proxy>
    </proxies>
</settings>
~`

Answer (score 1):

I used the following dependency - works for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>velocity-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>velocity-tools-generic</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```